# Match 2 data frames by date and column name to get values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames (they are already in a data frame format but for illustration, I created them as a dictionary first):

```
first = {
        'Date':['2013-02-14','2013-03-03','2013-05-02','2014-10-31'],
        'Name':['Felix','Felix','Peter','Paul']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(first)
```

And

```
 second = {
        'Date':['2013-02-28','2013-03-31','2013-05-30','2014-10-31'],
        'Felix':['Value1_x','Value2_x','Value3_x','Value4_x'],
        'Peter':['Value1_y','Value2_y','Value3_y','Value4_y']}


df2 = pd.DataFrame(second)
```

Now, I'd like to add an additional column to `df1` containing the `values` of `df2` if the `df1.Date` matches the `df2.Date` by year and month (the day does not usually match since `df1` contains end of month dates) AND if the column name of `df2` matches the according `df1.Name` values.

So the result should look like this:

```
df_new = {
        'Date':['2013-02-14','2013-03-03','2013-05-02','2014-10-31'],
        'Name':['Felix','Felix','Peter','Paul'],
        'Values':['Value1_x','Value2_x','Value3_y','NaN']}

df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_new)
```

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

I considered creating additional columns for `year` and `month` (`df1['year']= df1['Date'].dt.year`) and then matching `df1[(df1['year'] == df2['year']) & (df1['month'] == df2['month'])]` and calling the `df2.column` but I cant figure out how to put everything together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, try not to post your data sets as images, b/c it's hard to help you out then.

I think the easiest thing to do would be to create a column in each data frame where the `Date` is rounded to the first day of each month.

```
df1['Date_round'] = df1['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
df2['Date_round'] = df2['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

Then reshape `df2` using `melt`.

```
df2_reshaped = df2.melt(id_vars=['Date','Date_round'], var_name='Name', value_name='Values')
```

And then you can join the data frames on `Date_round` and `Name` using `pd.merge`.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2_reshaped.drop('Date', axis=1), how='left', on=['Date_round', 'Name'])
```